# Object not rendering/Object teleporting. Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view

I created this Sci-Fi thing and the ships (which I made in a different blender project) are not rendering. I can't find anything that can help me. I am using Blender 2.8.

[image: enter link description here]

This is the render: [Google photos link to large render output](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNLWGjIUf251WMIavp0rGkmyG0fA4CadzelXNxID245mGAbCdAtQxXl5pqKSxOEfA?key=OXYzN2c0YWpPekwwUW1MTEFPbVBxZEpweGdHRW93)

Also, when I load the save, all of the ships go to the middle where you can't see them, which makes it look like the final render. So the issue might be that the ships keep teleporting to the middle.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried to fix it but the image is too large.  Going to leave it to the OP to sort out, but tidied up as best I could

Comment: Just fixed it. There was an animation on the ships. I deleted them and everything was working. Thanks for the help.